# awk difference between commands from file and from commandline

Tags: awk

The following script

```
#! /bin/bash

B=5

#FILE INPUT
cat <<EOF > awk.in
BEGIN{b=$B;printf("B is %s\n", b)}
EOF
awk -f awk.in sometextfile.txt

#COMMANDLINE INPUT
awk 'BEGIN{b=$B;printf("B is %s\n", b)}' sometextfile.txt
```

produces the output

```
B is 5
B is
```

The commands I am issuing to awk are exactly the same, so why is the variable B interpreted correctly in the first case but not in the latter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```
awk 'BEGIN{b=$B;printf("B is %s\n", b)}' sometextfile.txt
```

The string literal `'BEGIN{b=$B;printf("B is %s\n", b)}'` is singly-quoted, therefore `$B` is not expanded and treated as awk code. In awk code, `B` is uninitialized, so `$B` becomes `$0`, which is in the `BEGIN` block empty.

In contrast, shell variables in here documents (as in your first example) are expanded, so `awk.in` ends up containing the value that `$B` had in the shell script. This, by the way, would have made writing awk code very painful as soon as you'd tried to use a field variable (named `$1`, `$2`, and so forth) or the full line (named `$0`) because you'd have to manually resolve the ambiguity between the awk fields and shell variables of the same name.

Use

```
awk -v b="$B" 'BEGIN{ printf("B is %s\n", b) }' sometextfile.txt
```

to make a shell variable known to awk code. Do not try to substitute it directly into awk code; it isn't necessary, you will hate writing awk code that way, and it leads to code injection problems, especially when `B` comes from an untrusted source.

Comment: Probably worth explicitly mentioning that variables in heredocs are expanded.

Comment: @EtanReisner You're probably right about that, so I added a bit.